# Paysify sentiment api returning null

Tags: php, api, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Good day fam. I have this sentiment analysis API from Paysify, which returns a JSON output but all of a sudden it is now returning `NULL` as output.
Please I help here, I have been trying to fix this for the past 4 hours, no headway.

```
   function detect_sentiment($string){
      $string = urlencode($string);
      $api_key = "< api key >";
      $url = 'https://api.paysify.com/sentiment?api_key='.$api_key.'&string='.$string.'';
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      $response = json_decode($result,true);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $response;
   }
      
  print_r(detect_sentiment("I love this product"));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not related to your code. The service you use has an issue on their server. If you try to open your Chrome browser and navigate to [https://api.paysify.com/sentiment?api_key={key}&string=I+love+this+product](https://api.paysify.com/sentiment?api_key=24ed361e9d48b3e84a7170fff53609&string=I%20love%20this%20product) you will see that the page can not be opened for an SSL error.

Please contact your API provider to resolve.

PS: remove the API Key from your initial question or anyone can use it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have written them, Pls which other sentiment analysis service can I use?

Comment: Amazon Comprehend and Google Cloud Native Language API are both very good. If my previous answer resolves your query, please mark it as accepted for future readers.